# Are there some methods to calculate the determinant allow collecting the multiple of matrix diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

When calculating the determinant, are there some methods that allow us to collect the multiple of one diagonal?

$$\begin{align*}\begin{array}{ccc} x & y & x+y \\ y & x+y & x \\ x+y & x & y \\\end{array}\end{align*}$$

For example, here we can collect/factor $(x+y)$, in general method, they are not allowed.
we can only collect rows or columns.

Comment: If you explain a bit more what question you're asking, I can improve my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander I think that the OP is hoping to factor $x+y$ somehow.

Answer (score 1):

With the matrix:
$$\begin{align*}\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \\\end{array}\end{align*}$$ the determinant is given by $a(ei-fh)-b(di-fg)+c(dh-eg)$.

In the matrix you give, $g=e=c=x+y$. All the terms except $-afh-bdi$ are divisible by $x+y$. Now, $-afh-bdi=-x^3-y^3=-(x^2-xy+y^2)(x+y)$. Thus, we can factor out $x+y$. In general this is not the case! For instance, if we changed any of $b,d,i$ to $-y$, then $-afh-bdi$ would equal $-x^3+y^3$ which does not have a factor of $x+y$. However, we see that if at least one of $b,d,i$ and one of $a,f,h$ are $0$, then you can always factor out $g=e=c$.

More generally, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of your matrix, then it will divide the determinant and so can be factored.

Comment: Yes, this is the so-called general determinant I mentioned.

Comment: Does what I added help?

Comment: Hi, your answer is helpful, since I just guess I can factor (x+y) in this example without calculation. However I'm also glad to know about something different linear algebra theories that allow us factor diagonals in general cases. Maybe other questions could be what kind of determinants could be factored in the diagonals...

Comment: If the coordinates of your matrix come from an algebraically closed field, then the matrix will have eigenvalues. The determinant of your matrix is just a product of the eigenvalues. Thus, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, you can factor it out of your determinant.